# CodeIgniter Error in Registration Validation

Tags: codeigniter

I got the following error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function set_userdata() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\jobsite\application\controllers\main.php on line 32**

I couldn't identify the error tho, Could you please help?

**Error Message Snapshot link:**
[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/16019653@N00/8626733197/in/photostream/lightbox/]

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->login();

    }
public function login(){
$this->load->view('login');
}

public function members(){
$this->load->view('members');

}

public function login_validation(){
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email', 'required|trim|xss_clear|callback_validation_credentials' );
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password', 'required|md5 ');

if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

$data = array (
'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
'is_logged_in' => 1

);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);  /*  Line 32   */

   redirect('main/members');

} else {$this->load->view('login') ;

         }


}

public function validation_credentials(){

$this->load->model('model_users');

if($this->model_users->can_log_in()) {
return true;
} else {
$this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentials', 'Incorrect UserName / Password');

return false;
}

}

    }
```

Comment: did you include the session library?

Comment: Yes tom . $autoload['packages'] = array('database','session');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to autoload in libraries, not packages:

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');

Comment: Oh by mistake I put sessions on Packages :D . thanks alot bro.

by the way May I know some examples for $autoload['packages'] ? why its using actually?

Comment: I think packages & the "third_party" directory is an idea that pretty much never materialized, especially now with Composer making great gains